# Does tinyxpath 1.3.1 support xpath 2.0?

Tags: c++, tinyxml, tinyxpath

I'm having some troubles computing complex xpaths with tinyxpath 1.3.1. Those xpaths are perfectly computed in this online xpath tester: http://www.qutoric.com/xslt/analyser/xpathtool.html.

xpath samples I'm using:

```
replace(/xdm:Information/xdm:ComponentGroup/xdm:Component[@componentType='mediaInput'][1]/media:MediaInput/dd:MediaInputID/text(), '[0-9]+', '')
/xdm:Information/xdm:ComponentGroup/xdm:Component[@componentType='mediaInput'][1]/@id
```

Does tinyxpath 1.3.1 support xpath 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not look like it.
From the SourceForge page for tinyxpath 1.3.1:

"Small footprint C++ library to extract an XPath 1.0 expression from an XML tree. Uses the TinyXML project to parse XML trees and store intermediate results. Runs on any platform. Optional use of STL. Overhead less than 100KB, including TinyXML."